# How to add MVC 5 authentication to Unity IoC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm currently working on implementing the new ASP.NET MVC 5 out-of-the box authentication into my application. However when using Unity as my IoC, I cannot use any portion of the AccountController because I'm given the error:

> The type IUserStore`1 does not have an accessible constructor.

This is my given unity setup which is called in the global.asax

```
public class DependencyConfig
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        container.RegisterType<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();

        container.RegisterType<ITeamRepository, TeamRepository>();

        container.RegisterType<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();

        return container;
    }
}
```

And here are the default constructors of a fresh AccountController.cs

```
public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new BusinessTrackerUsersContext())))
{

}

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}
```

And here are the items being called in the AccountController constructors. These are the defaults with new names.

```
public class BusinessTrackerUsersContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public BusinessTrackerUsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

}
```

Any help would be widely appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because you have two constructors on your controller, unity will pick up the one with longer parameter list, the latter. It requires the UserManager to be injected.

Although you haven't listed it here, I suspect is has an only constructor that requires the IUserStore. Unity tried to resolve it and can't find any constructor it could use directly or resolve its parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Though hutchonoid has the actual syntax to register it, you have explained it so I can understand why.

Answer (score 33):

I agree with Wiktor.

You could register the parameterless constructor with Unity though and stop it taking the longer parameter by doing this:

```
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's exactly what I was after.

Comment: Thanks great help.  I went here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionconstructor.injectionconstructor(v=pandp.30).aspx) to further my understanding of the InjectionConstructor object.  If you wanted to map to a constructor in the AccountController with multiple parameters you can pass those as an array of objects to the InjectionConstructor.

Comment: @hutchonoid when I do what you've suggested, my `account/login` returns a **404 error**! I'm on MVC5 with latest version of Unity.

Comment: @hutchonoid You are spot on with your recommendation.